# Monitoring for Errors & Error Notifications throughout Integration Test

Tags: selenium, integration, intern

My question is twofold. I'm using Intern as an integration/e2e testing framework with a couple different services in various client-side JS frameworks. I'd like to be able to flag two things throughout the tests:

- api call to fetch a resource returns a 400 or 500-level status
- an error notice/div matching some css appears on the page, but fades away relatively quickly

In the first case i've looked at using something like a `window.onerror` script on the client, but not sure it would work or be the best in this case.

In the second, I could probably check for errors div at specific points, but this wouldn't necessarily cover something like an autosave. What I would really like is a listener across the entire test.

Answer (score 0):

An `onerror` check is probably the most straightforward solution. Just install it on the page at the beginning of the test, have it set a global if any errors occur, and check the global at the end of the test.

Another potential option (which I haven't tested) may be to start a `find` for an error popup in a separate command chain and have it running concurrently to the main test chain. This would require setting your find timeout to a relatively large value (large enough so that the find would last through the entire test). Use `Promise.all` to combine the two Command chains, something like:

```
var load = this.remote.get('somePage').setFindTimeout(somethingBig);
var errorCheck = load.findByCssSelector('.errorClass').then(function () {
    throw new Error("shouldn't have found this");
});
var test = load.doTestThings();
return Promise.all([ errorCheck, test ]);
```